# How to Build a small Programm to change values in a Sql database

Tags: mysql, desktop-application

At first I want to say hi :)

I am completely new to Sql and windows App development. Iam a student in Java in Germany.

But now I have to build a small app for my family business. We resell videogames and the support for our old inventory management software ended up forever.

I need something like a search field to search for titles, Ean and so on. Then it would be great to highlight what I found, edit the stock, price and sell price and pass it to another table and go on with the next entry.

When I'm done I just need to print the list + total price and update the sql database with that information.

If someone brings up some games to sell, I scan them, edit the values and when I'm done, print and update.

I just want you to point me in the right direction. What do I need, to keep it simple. I don't want to end up going in the wrong direction.

I hope my explanation says what I need. Thank you guys

Comment: I suggest Perl is quite matched for desktop-application. Since its support GUI and mysql.